# R, get the n'th occurence of pattern using regex

Tags: r, regex

I have strings like:

```
s <- "text-32190-3910-text-1671"
```

I would like to get only the n'th occurence, e.g. the second, of a pattern, e.g. a group of digits (a number, "\d+"). Thus, the 2nd occurence of digits in `s` would give me "3910". Thought it must be simply done by a grep() (and family) construct, but couldnt find an example at SO (?).

EDIT: Another case would be:

```
s2 <- "jklsdKSfdkdlsKLLSDK-kdslkSKKSK"
```

I would then like to get the third occurence of a block of capital letters [A-Z]+, in `s2` this would be "SKKSK".

Comment: Didnt understand ur question.

Comment: Given a regex pattern (like a number), and if pattern occurs mulitple times, how can I get e.g. the 2nd occurence from the string.

Comment: If you mean, there is a '-' and you want to split the second occurence all the time , then read the below answer.

Comment: a clumsy regex way is to extract all matching patterns, and then extract the nth term `n = 2 ; regmatches(s, gregexpr("\\d+", s) )[[1]][n]`

Comment: Hm, that might be a solution, clumpsy or not. I appears rather general once you have your pattern described.

Comment: yes, it seems to work, but im sure the regex maestros will be able to this more simply

Comment: Would be interesting to see other approaches to this simple problem!

Comment: how is SKKSK the third 'occurence'?

Comment: This is similar to regmatches/gregexpr but uses a package and is slightly simpler: `library(gsubfn); strapplyc(s, "\\d+", simplify = c)[2]`

Comment: @user3375672 Yes but how is SKKSK the 'third' occurence? It hasnt 'occured' more than once. Is the word occurence used correctly here? What is third occurence?

Comment: @MaxPD: Its the 3rd occurence of pattern "[A-Z]+" (the 1st and 2nd would return "KS" and "KLLSDK". Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by user20650 to use a mix of `gregexpr()` and `regmatches()` is a good way to approach this:

```
R> s <- "text-32190-3910-text-1671"
R> regmatches(s, gregexpr("\\d+", s) )[[1]][2]
[1] "3910"
R> s2 <- "jklsdKSfdkdlsKLLSDK-kdslkSKKSK"
R> regmatches(s2, gregexpr("[A-Z]+", s2) )[[1]][2]
[1] "KLLSDK"
```